# Image and Div overlay, not quite working

Tags: html, css

This should be a quick question i think. I am trying to create a simple overlay over a div using hover. This half works, because the image does not get covered.

```
<div class="puzzlePieceContainer">
    <img class="back-link puzzleTileBack-4" style="display: none; margin-left: 0px;" alt="" />
    <div class="boxShadow arrowMargin">
        <div class="overlayContainer overlayBox">
            <div id="puzzleTile-4" class="puzzleTiles">
                <img src="http://debtsettlementlogic.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/debt-solutions-florida.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="199" />
                <h2 style="padding-top: 10px;">Solutions</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .overlayBox:hover   
{  
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
```

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3aRY4/

How do I get the effect that the overlay covers the entire div, and not just everything around the picture?

Comment: What do you mean only half of the image works? The background of the entire div is indeed changing.

Comment: @compid Maybe it was not clear enough, i have changed the wording in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to add the overlay via a pseudo element. Just absolutely position the pseudo element relative to the parent and have it cover the entire element.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Esdsm/)

```
.overlayBox {
    position:relative;
}
.overlayBox:hover:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    top:0; bottom:0;
    left:0; right:0;
}
```

Comment: There is one issue though, i use jquery to click on the div and it causes a click action to slide content down. This no longer works when using position absolute.

Comment: @RHK-S8 Do you mind linking to the example? I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Yeh i would love to, however it is behind a firewall on the development servers. I will try and bring it across into fiddler

Comment: It might be easier to explore alternatives to using position absolute? in the mean i will start copying code to fiddler

Comment: i fixed the issue, thank you. I accepted your response as the answer.

Comment: @RHK-S8 See the updated CSS in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/M5N2W/). The problem was that the pseudo element was positioned over the other elements. You therefore couldn't click through it. The solution is to simply add the pseudo element to `#puzzleTile-4` when hovering over `.overlayBox`. As an alternatively, you could have added `pointer-events:none` to the initial example in order to allow you to click through the element:http://jsfiddle.net/BqHdL/ Go with the former solution, though, `pointer-events` isn't widely supported.